# Combine strings in list to form words starting with capital letter

Tags: python

NLP newbie here. I have a list of strings, and I would like to combine them so that each string starts with a capital letter. What is the most efficient way to do so?

Here is the list: `[' Ye', 'oks', 'am', '-', 'd', 'ong', ' Gang', 'nam', '-', 'gu Seoul', ' Korea']`.

Desidered output: `['Yeoksam-dong', 'Gangnam-gu Seoul', 'Korea']`. `['Yeoksam-dong', 'Gangnam-gu', 'Seoul', 'Korea']` is also fine.

This is the solution I'm working to improve:

```
places = [' Ye', 'oks', 'am', '-', 'd', 'ong', ' Gang', 'nam', '-', 'gu Seoul', ' Korea']
num_places = 0
Temp = []
for ii in range(len(places)):
    loc = str(" ".join(places[ii].split()))
    print(loc, loc[0].isupper())
    if str(" ".join(places[ii + 1].split()))[0].isupper() == True:
        places_words.append(loc)
        num_places += 1
    else:
        Temp.append(loc)
        print(Temp)
```

Comment: Whats the output? Is not clear from your description

Comment: Each word starts with a capital letter.

Comment: Could you show us your code and what error you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach:

```
from itertools import tee


def pairwise(iterable):
    # pairwise('ABCDEFG') --> AB BC CD DE EF FG
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)


data = [' Ye', 'oks', 'am', '-', 'd', 'ong', ' Gang', 'nam', '-', 'gu Seoul', ' Korea']

# find the indices of the words that ara capitalized 
indices = [i for i, e in enumerate(data) if e.strip()[0].isupper()] + [len(data)]

# iterate pairwise and join the strings 
res = ["".join(data[start:end]).strip() for start, end in pairwise(indices)]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
['Yeoksam-dong', 'Gangnam-gu Seoul', 'Korea']
```

Alternative using [more_itertools](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html),

```
from more_itertools import split_before

data = [' Ye', 'oks', 'am', '-', 'd', 'ong', ' Gang', 'nam', '-', 'gu Seoul', ' Korea']

chunks = split_before(map(str.strip, data), lambda e: e[0].isupper())

res = ["".join(chunk).strip() for chunk in chunks]
print(res)
```